# how to add airplay function in our application?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AirPlay support, MPMoviePlayerController and MPVolumeView relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730973/airplay-support-mpmovieplayercontroller-and-mpvolumeview-relation)

I am implementing one iphone application in which I want to add airplay functionality.

I dont know is possible of not.

Please give me idea about that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope these all links will help u out..this http://stackoverflow.com/q/6391231/814183 and also this http://stackoverflow.com/q/5311373/814183 and u require to go through this ... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS4_3.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010567-SW2

Answer (score 0):

If the device supporting airplay is enabled and within the same network, the player provides the option to play via airplay automatically. However there is a explicit flag which you can set stating to enable airplay for `MPMovieController`. Youtube player detects its autmatically, so does the quicktime player.