# How to do screen mirroring using AirPlay from the application (not from control centre) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, airplay, mpvolumeview

I am using `MPVolumeView` to show `AirPlay` button. I need to show a custom wallpaper to `Apple` `TV` through mirroring with audio. Audio is playing properly on `Apple` `TV` but wallpaper image is not showing. I am using `AVAudioController` for playing audio. I have checked `YouTube` application in which screen mirroring is working from application for video playing. Is it possible to screen mirroring within the app using `AVAudioController` ?

Help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's slight confusion with the terminology. Mirroring is something that happens automatically when user selects an Airplay output device using system controls. AirPlay mirroring shows on remote display exactly the same that you see on the device.

Comment: @LeontyDeriglazov we can show different different views to external device and our iPhone. But I can not do it from my App while I can do it from iOS control panel.

Comment: I have seen youtube app and Photo(iOS Native app). We can enable screen mirroring from app. How can I do the same?

Comment: • YouTube plays a video and Apple supports this use case with MPVolumeView (refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730973/airplay-support-mpmovieplayercontroller-and-mpvolumeview-relation)

Comment: • As you might guess Apple does not always play by its App Store rules with their apps. You are most likely not getting the same level of control over AirPlay using any public method.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, external display associated with AirPlay will only become active (and post appropriate notification) when you enable AirPlay mirroring in control panel. There appears to be [no way to enable mirroring programmatically](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/04/23/ios-mirroring-and-programmatic-airplay-selection/).

MPVolumeView can help user redirect audio to AirPlay speakers, it has nothing to do with display mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html

Basically it's about creating a 2nd `UIWindow`, if an external display is available. There you can show your wallpaper, which is an image, I assume. Should be simple to put that via an `UIImageView` into that 2nd `UIWindow`.

Comment: Thanks for response @plu. I have created UI for second screen. It is working if I switch on screen mirroring from control panel. But it not working when I tap on Apple Tv in available screens within my app. I am showing available screen using MPVolumeView.

Answer (score 0):

You can screen mirroring within the app using AVPlayer property.

That property is

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL usesAirPlayVideoWhileAirPlayScreenIsActive NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(5_0, 6_0);
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);.
```

The default value of `usesAirPlayVideoWhileAirPlayScreenIsActive` and `usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive` is  NO.

`usesAirPlayVideoWhileAirPlayScreenIsActive` is no effect if `allowsAirPlayVideo` is NO.

And `usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive` is no effiect if `allowsExternalPlayback` is NO.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to listen for the screen connection/disconnection notifications:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleScreenDidConnectNotification:)
               name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleScreenDidDisconnectNotification:)
               name:UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
```

In the name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification you will see that your device now has 2 screens and you can do your setup.