# How to show Airplay panel programmatically on iOS using flutter

Tags: objective-c, flutter, dart

The desired output looks like this,

[image: desired output]

how to show this on click event programmatically using flutter(even with native code if possible), it's really appreciated if anyone could show an example.
If there is no direct approach to this then a platform specific example  using MethodChannel is also very welcome. Native code example must be in Objective C.

Additionally I have tried to use [flutter_to_airplay](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_to_airplay) but project fails to run and also has other functionalities that are not needed in this context, what is needed is showing Airplay panel only.

(Answer by M123 native code completely not working)

Comment: Do you want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284532/6131611) from native?

Comment: @pavel yes if its with a clear example how to trigger it from flutter code

Comment: try this package hope work for you https://pub.dev/packages/better_player

Comment: @Mohammad_Asef the problem is not showing notifications, but triggering the airplay panel upon click inside flutter app.

Comment: Why did the flutter_to_airplay plugin didn't work, what have you tried

Comment: @M123 after pubgetting the package the project wont even run on the device, and also i want only this functionality

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/ios-add-an-airplay-button-to-an-app) is a example how to open the AirPlayPanel in objective c.

#### Setup flutter

First you have to create a channel. To start communicating to the native code.

> All channel names used in a single app must be unique; prefix the
> channel name with a unique ‘domain prefix

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('stack.M123.dev/airplay');
```

---

Then you have to invoke a method on the method channel.

```
  Future<void> _openAirPlay() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('openAirPlay');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('error');
    }


  }
```

---

#### Native part

Now the flutter part is done.

First you have to add suppport for swift. For this open the ios folder in the flutter root with XCode.

```
Expand Runner > Runner in the Project navigator.
```

Open the AppDelegate.m located under Runner > Runner in the Project navigator.

Create a FlutterMethodChannel and add a handler inside the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. Make sure to use the same channel name as was used on the Flutter client side.

```
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
  FlutterViewController* controller = (FlutterViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;

  FlutterMethodChannel* airPlayChannel= [FlutterMethodChannel
                                          methodChannelWithName:@"stack.M123.dev/airplay"
                                          binaryMessenger:controller.binaryMessenger];

  [airPlayChannel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall* call, FlutterResult result) {
    // Note: this method is invoked on the UI thread.
      if ([@"getBatteryLevel" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
int returnValue = [weakSelf openAirPlay];


  result(@(returnValue));

  }];

  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Add the method in the AppDelegate class, just before @end

```
- (int)openAirPlay {
    //Open air play
    return (int)(100);
  
}
```

**Discalimer**: I am not a IOS developer so the steps are mostly theoretical.
I am following the official guide from Flutter. It can be found in full length [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab).

Comment: thanks for the detailed example but as I mentioned in the question `platform specific example (in objective c) ` my iOS side of the code is objective c and your example is coded in swift, can you edit your example with objective c ? I updated my question to make it more clear it must be in objective c.

Comment: @user6597752 Updated the native part to objective c. Hope this helps, but I can't confirm, that it works.

Comment: thanks again but please the syntax isn't even correct (the objc) I couldn't run your example on ios, can you please try running your example ? I cant correct it bcoz i hv no idea about objective c

Comment: @user6597752 sorry, like I said, I am not a IOS developer myself, and I have no possebility to test the native code, since I am a Windows user. Please try to follow the official guide I linked in the answer

Comment: The official guide is about connecting the flutter code with native code and that has been done, my issue is with the code that opens the airplay panel, there no official guide that i can follow which shows how to open airplay panel using obj c, is there ?