# Is it posible to MIRROR the screen programatically within the app and not in control center?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, mirror

**I would like to have the same functionality as when I tap the screen mirroring button on control center, but from inside my app.**

Do someone knows how to achieve this?

[image: Control Center]

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356127/how-to-do-screen-mirroring-using-airplay-from-the-application-not-from-control) can help